# Coredata: Performance issue when saving a lot of data

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I want to fill my app's database with some data from a CSV file during initial startup (50'000 entries). I however run into performance issues...it is way too slow right now and in the simulator takes like 2-3 minutes. My context hierarchy is as follows:

parentContext (separate thread)
context (main thread)
importContext (separate thread)

The code:

```
for (NSString *row in rows){
            columns = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            //Step 1
            Airport *newAirport = [Airport addAirportWithIcaoCode: [columns[0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                                                    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
                                                             name:columns[1]
                                                         latitude:[columns[2] doubleValue]
                                                        longitude:[columns[3] doubleValue]
                                                        elevation:[columns[4] doubleValue]
                                                        continent:columns[5]
                                                          country:columns[6]
                                                      andIataCode:columns[7]
                                           inManagedObjectContext:self.cdh.importContext];
            rowCounter++;
            //Increment progress
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [progress setProgress:rowCounter/totalRows animated:YES];
                [progress setNeedsDisplay];
            });

            // STEP 2: Save new objects to the parent context (context).
            //if(fmodf(rowCounter, batchSize)== 0) {
                NSError *error;
                if (![self.cdh.importContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"error saving %@", error);
                }
            //}

            // STEP 3: Turn objects into faults to save memory
            [self.cdh.importContext refreshObject:newAirport mergeChanges:NO];
        }
```

If I activate the if with modulo for batch size 2000 in step 2, then of course only every 2000nd entry gets saved and then the performance is fast. But like this it is super slow and I wonder why? I have my import context in a separate thread and still it lags very much...

Comment: Is it always the same CSV file? Put the initial persistent store inside your app and copy to a suitable location during initial startup.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it is enough to issue a single `save` after processing all your entries. You don't need to save this often. Just do it after the `for` loop. I see that you try to save memory by turning the objects into faults each time, so this might require a `save` (did not try this before).

I suggest you use `@autoreleasepool` instead and let the system decide where to save memory:

```
for (NSString *row in rows) {
    @autoreleasepool {
    // Just STEP 1 here
    ...
    }
}
NSError *error;
if (![self.cdh.importContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error saving %@", error);
}
```